# installing apache, php5 on windows 7 64 bit [production]

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, php, mysql, xampp

The easiest way to install apache, php, mysql and phpmyadmin on windows is to download and install [XAMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). The problem is that it is meant for development purposes and is not recommended for production environment.

So, i need to install all the components and link them together i.e. [php](http://windows.php.net/), [apache](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/), [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and phpMyAdmin.

I have a 64 bit machine, a 64 bit Windows 7 Ultimate OS, and would like to install 64 bit application in order to meet the architecture at all the three layers (hardware, OS, application).

Apache and MySQL are available as 64 bit but for php, 64 bit build is available only for version 5.5 onwards and that is experimental too.

I want to have a recommendation for the packages.

1. Apache 64, MySQL 64, PHP 5.5 64 (experimental)
2. Apache 64, MySQL 64, PHP 5.5 32
3. Apache 32, MySQL 32, PHP 5.5 32

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog](http://www.anindya.com/) which contains 64 bit binaries for apache and php. Going to try them.